# Basic Design - Rest communication with Symfony 4 projects

Tags: rest, symfony4, api-platform.com

I would like know, how big api frameworks in Symfony
4 would look like. For example, there are three Apis:

- Price Api (data comes from a different system)
- Product Api (data comes from a different system)
- User Api

and several symfony client projects (web-catalog, 
basket, special product configurators ..) will use 
it for their internal work.

I have seen that there is new project for Apis. 
Api Platform. My concern here is that we dont have 
simple Api request with get, pull, post on single 
tables. It will be more like

```
->getPrice($productId, $lang, $areaCode, $distributor, $userId)
```

with a lot of internal logic behind the request. 
Are there existing projects with complex request?
Api platform is pretty new to me, and there is
only a pretty simple demo....

To make a Rest Request on the client side ... there are 
different ways

- curl yourself
- GuzzleHttp
- Unirest
- ...

Is there no standard method inside Symfony 4? (We had 
problems in the past, that current external libaries 
to not support older symfony versions...).

Thank you & Best Regards

Comment: Regarding the client-side, there is not recommended way, but most People use Guzzle or HttpPlug.
Regarding the server-side, API Platform is for all kind of API, but is mainly REST (hypermedia) oriented. What you describe looks more to a service-oriented API (SOAP). Anyway your getPrice example can easily be implemented using API Platform's builtin filters: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#doctrine-orm-filters

I'll need more details to see if it fits your need or if you should switch to a different pattern (such as SOAP).